# Need to remove white space in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the 'make' theme for wordpress and need to remove the white space both above each headline and above and below the 'read more' link. If you go to the home page of my site you should see what I mean. Also above and below the 'older posts' link at the bottom of the page. My site is: Archerydude.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some CSS to remove the padding and margin that's causing the whitespace.

I always use a child theme for custom css, more info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

But the simplest solution is to install a [custom css plugin](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/) and add the following css:

```
body .post {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
}
body .site-main [class*="navigation"] {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Like Kirk Beard said. please read 
[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and remove your question.